# mysql sorting string according to number first

Tags: mysql, string, sorting

I don't know is it possible or not I have subject code stings like this

```
Math 451
Math 451a
Math 452
Math 452a
Math 452b
```

I want query that would sort these string like this

```
Math 451
Math 452
Math 451a
Math 452a
Math 452b
```

I tried

```
CAST(SUBSTR(subjects.code,INSTR(subjects.code, " ") + 1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

but not working as expected 
thank you for your any help and suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first sort by length of string and then by string itself:

```
SELECT code
FROM subjects
ORDER BY LENGTH(code), code;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/IDJR7395)**